# Best place to format date expressions. SSRS side or SQL Server side?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently working on a SSRS dashboard report and this report has a graph that displays a comparison of values for current and previous year.
The query I have on SQL side returns a WeekStartDate and WeekEndDate columns in the result set. For displaying the data on the report, I need to have a formatted date.

I have two options here:

1. To format the date in required format in a derived column (derives from WeekStartDate and WeekEndDate columns) on the SQL side and use this column directly on SSRS.
2. NOT HAVING A DERIVED COLUMN ON SQL SIDE, but just writing an SSRS expression to format the dates on the SSRS side.

I would like to know which one is more preferable, effective from performance standpoints.

Other information: If we may have to consider other factors, there are 3 other data sets used by this same report as this is a dashboard report, and there are various other expressions conversions and conversions performed on the SSRS side as well. Also, the result sets are huge.

Looking forward for your thoughts and suggestions.
Cheers.

Comment: All formatting on the client side, as culture may change w/o the back end knowing. Then you'll have to pass the culture to the back end and write extra processing.

Answer (score 4):

Formatting should **always** be part of the front end, not the backend (or even worse: a database!).

In your report, chose one of the predefined date formats (not some hardcoded format) to make sure that users with different locale settings can see their data in their preferred format.